# How to get dynamically URL to load same page?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

How to, lets say, get wordpress/articles/post-1 load same page as wordpress/articles/post-2. Why i´m trying to do this is because that I´m buildin a page that loads articles through an external API.
So, based on the last part of URL I call the API and load that specific article.

I´ve managed to succeed through the .htaccess file, but it does only works with numbers, not with letters (article/123 works, article/abc throws a 404)... Assuming wordpress is reading it as som kind of page that´s not existing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /article/
RewriteRule  ^article/(.*)/ /site/article/?aa=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Do you want `domain.com/articles/post-1` showing the WordPress page with 'post-1' slug (id)?

Comment: Actually I want the "articles" to deside what template i wanna use. And because i´m using API "post-1" doesn´t exists and therefore throws an 404... So i´m trying to show the same page/template for all under "articles" (having a hard time to explain this even to myself ;)).

Comment: Very hard :)) You mean `articles/post-1` doesn't exist but you need to show something? so what should be displayed in `articles/post-1` and what is your dynamic part of URL and data?

Comment: :) I want to do like this. Everything under /articles/* will load an template. In that templat I will use the "*" to call for a specific post from an axternal API, and print it out on the page... So regardles if its /articles/hello or /post-1 or whatever it should always use the same template.

Comment: Check my answer I think It should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have this `http://domain/articles/abc123`:

You should manually set WordPressPageID with WordPress articles page id and aa is abc123

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^articles/([^/]*)$ /index.php?page_id=WordPressPageID&aa=$1 [L]
#  original wordpress rewrites should placed here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called dynamic 404 redirect. Now I understand your case i.e. if the particular post/page doesn't exist then it should redirect to any running post/page(decided template). I mean instead of throwing 404 error it should show some existing page.

Add the following code into your `/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/functions.php` file to achieve a dynamic redirect for all 404's:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'unlisted_jobs_redirect' );
function unlisted_jobs_redirect()
{
    // check if is a 404 error, and it's on your jobs custom post type
    if( is_404() && is_singular('your-job-custom-post-type') )
    {
        // then redirect to yourdomain.com/jobs/
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/jobs/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 301 permanent and 302 temporarily redirect.

If you’re working on the main URL and want to temporarily redirect visitors to another page for some time, then you may need to use a 302 redirect rule.
`Oldpage.html` is that particular page/post (this may be exist or not).
`Newpage.html` is the new landing page/post.

```
Redirect 302 /oldpage.html http://www.yourwebsite.com/newpage.html
```